# Implementing drag-and-drop from one JPanel to another

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to drag-and-drop in Swing. I have a `JPanel` that draws an image with a caption superimposed on it. I want to implement drag and drop on this `JPanel`, but after going through some documentation and tutorials I didn't find any usable pointers on how it's done for this type of component. For starters, it doesn't have a `setDragEnabled` function.

Can I make a `JPanel` draggable? I want to use this DnD maneuver to pass a reference to a certain object from one panel to another.

Comment: *"Can I make a JPanel draggable?"*  Its draggable if added to a `JList`.

Comment: http://www.bryanesmith.com/documents/drag-and-drop-panel-demo/index.html?

Comment: @StanislavL I had another look at that code example but it is throwing [exceptions](http://pastebin.com/zvXX5WJ2) all over the place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this can help you.

[Drag and Drop of complex custom objects in Java](http://softwareisart.blogspot.com/2011/11/drag-and-drop-of-complex-custom-objects.html)

Comment: Your code sample helped me work out a solution! Thanks... the bounty is yours!

Answer (score 3):

You can implement drag-and-drop behavior on any `JComponent`. See the [`setTransferHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setTransferHandler%28javax.swing.TransferHandler%29) method.

The `setDragEnabled` method is typically provided on components where a good default D&D behavior can be implemented in the JDK. In such cases you can just activate the default D&D by calling that method.

On a `JPanel` they (=the Swing developers) could probably not think of any decent default D&D behavior, so you will have to implement your own `TransferHandler`. I strongly suggest to read the [Drag-and-drop tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html) before starting

Comment: I'm having some issues with the drop side of things. Here are some relevant code snippets: http://pastebin.com/2UdnxSBH I see *[DRAG] Created Transferable javax.activation.DataHandler@9da2ea* followed by *[DROP] Detected drop java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext$TransferableProxy@b315c1*. `Transferable` isn't an instance of `DataHandler`, which is what I'd have expected.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify that I'm trying to drag a `JPanel` to another `JPanel`. The [Top-Level Drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/toplevel.html) tutorial only covers dragging files onto the application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how viable sounds but when I needed to drag and drop panels I did it this way:

Firstable I implemented action events for dragable panels and containers, it can be both

I used a static variables for selected parent, selected child and current panel

when the mouse is over a panel you set it as the current panel

when you click , mouse down, whatever, you check if currentpanel is the clicked one and set is as child panel

when the mouse is over a panel and child panel is not null, then it seems that you're dragging, current panel will turn into parent panel once you release the mouse

you have to add some validation.

If a panel is being dragged you can use your own implementation, it could be follow the mouse coords or just highlight it and highlight the parent, I used this last option to simulate the drag

---

ok I wrote this, is so buggy but this is the idea:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author porfiriopartida
 */
public class DraggablePanel extends JDesktopPane implements ContainerPanel{
    public ContainerPanel parent;

    static DraggablePanel over;
    static ContainerPanel overParent;
    static DraggablePanel dragging;
    static ContainerPanel draggingParent;

    public DraggablePanel(){
        this(null);
    }
    public DraggablePanel(ContainerPanel parent){
        this.parent = parent;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        setBounds(0,0,100,100);

        if(parent != null)
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
                DraggablePanel src = (DraggablePanel) me.getSource();
                DraggablePanel.over = src;
                DraggablePanel.overParent = DraggablePanel.over.parent;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
                if(DraggablePanel.over != null && DraggablePanel.dragging != null && DraggablePanel.overParent != null){
                    Rectangle bounds = DraggablePanel.dragging.getBounds();
                    bounds.x = me.getX();
                    bounds.y = me.getY();

                    //Remove child from parent
                    DraggablePanel.dragging.parent.removePanel(DraggablePanel.dragging);

                    if(DraggablePanel.dragging.parent != DraggablePanel.overParent){
                        //add child to new parent
                        DraggablePanel.overParent.addPanel(DraggablePanel.dragging, bounds);
                    }
                    else{
                        //same parent selected
                        DraggablePanel.dragging.parent.addPanel(DraggablePanel.dragging, bounds);
                    };
                    DraggablePanel.dragging.parent = DraggablePanel.overParent;
                }

                //cleaning variables
                DraggablePanel.dragging = null;
                DraggablePanel.over = null;
                DraggablePanel.draggingParent = null;
                DraggablePanel.overParent = null;

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                DraggablePanel.dragging = (DraggablePanel) me.getSource();
                DraggablePanel.draggingParent = DraggablePanel.dragging.parent;
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
                super.mouseEntered(me);
                ContainerPanel src = (ContainerPanel) me.getSource();
                DraggablePanel.overParent = src;
                if (DraggablePanel.draggingParent == null || DraggablePanel.draggingParent == src) {
                    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
                } else {
                    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 2));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void addPanel(DraggablePanel panel) {
        panel.parent = this;
        add(panel);

            repaint();
            revalidate();

            try {
            getParent().repaint();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void addPanel(DraggablePanel panel, Rectangle bounds) {
        setBounds(bounds);
        addPanel(panel);
    }

    @Override
    public void removePanel(DraggablePanel panel) {
        remove(panel);
    }



    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        JTextField tf = new JTextField("textfield");
        JButton btn = new JButton("Button");

        DraggablePanel desktop = new DraggablePanel();
        frame.add(desktop);

        DraggablePanel p1 = new DraggablePanel(desktop);
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        p1.add(tf);
        p1.setBounds(0,0,100,50);
        tf.setBounds(5,5,80,30);

        DraggablePanel p2 = new DraggablePanel(desktop);
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        p2.add(btn);
        p2.setBounds(50,50,50,30);
        btn.setBounds(5,5,30,20);

        desktop.add(p1);
        desktop.add(p2);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```